# Swift: How to change height of stack row without affection other rows filled equally?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am fairly new and try to understand the whole concept of views and stacks right now by creating a simple app with a vertical full screen stack view filled equally (all four constraints are set to 0). Just like this (hopefully you understand my illustration):

[image]

That works fine, but now I'd like to add another row in the stack on top, but with a fixed height. The other stack rows should still be filled equally. Just like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?
Obviously the stack is filled equally and set all three views to the same height.

When I try to set a height constraint for the new view I get a red error line indicating that there is a problem with the top constraint of the stack.

So is this somehow possible to put a view on top, but keep the rest of the stack filled equally?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a simple video for you, I hope it would make things clear. 
You'd need to wrap the 2 last views into another StackView.

[Video on dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gtrjs7af5q2b6s/stackoverflow_44483399.mov?dl=0)

**UPDATE:**

1. Put your last 2 subviews into vertical stackview
2. Set that stackview's ditribution to `Fill Equally`
3. Set root stackview's ditribution to `Fill`

Comment: The only question remain is: What would I do to have a leading and trailing space of let's say 15 on both sides for just the old views (not the new). Again just setting the constraints on the stack doesn't work anymore?

Comment: You should set top's UIStackView's alignment to Center, and then set the leading and trailing constraints of nested UIStackView to 15, thus you wouldn't get any errors.

Comment: @noir_eagle: Please can you include the core of the answer as text in your post as link only answers become useless once the links become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Don't fill equally.

You need **view1** and **view2** to be equal height then give a specific height to view1(128) and give view2 **equal height**

and then give your smallView to your desired height(30)

Lastly give one of your views to a width(such as 240)

and that's it. Don't forget to auto-layout your stackView as well.

[image]

and my hierarchy.

[image]